# Authenticate User's Unix Credentials via Web Browser

Tags: unix, authentication, linux-server

Can anyone give me tips on how to authenticate a user's Unix credentials through the browser?

I am basically giving access to some file viewing and I want to make sure the users are authenticated but don't want to make a whole additional password and username that they have to remember.

Comment: ask user for username/password, calculate the hash of password and compare it to /etc/shadow. Problem is shadow file is visible only for root

Comment: would it be very bad practice to have the webapp get root to run a script to compare the attempted password hash to the /etc/shadow hash?

Comment: are there alternatives or tools to use that allow me to still compare an attempted password with the unix one external to the unix login itself?

Answer (score 1):

There are few *transparent* methods for this, unfortunately.

- In a centrally managed network, you could possibly use Kerberos, with mod_auth_gssapi or mod_auth_kerb on the web server side (aka "HTTP Negotiate"). Kerberos is very secure, but can be a pain to configure for web usage (not all browsers support it, and only some allow it by default).
- If all the computers are trusted (i.e. users are guaranteed to not tamper with root-installed software), the Ident protocol (RFC 1413) is a possibility, but the authentication it provides is very weak.

But most often, your only option is to ask for a password.

- If the users have accounts in `/etc/passwd`, as mentioned in your comment, running a privileged program is unfortunately the *only* way to verify a received password against `/etc/shadow`.

  If you do this, don't write your own scripts through `sudo`, because you *will* get input validation wrong the first time, and because it's a solved problem already. Pick something well-known, for example Cyrus `saslauthd` (which can run in `-a pam` mode); that way your website will not need any privileges beyond connecting to the `saslauthd` socket.